# Convert EPOCH string in filename to readable format

Tags: shell-script, rename, date, timestamps

My knowledge of Unix is not very good.
I'm trying to write a shell script to rename a set of files in a directory, like `1709532255.mp4` to `20240304_070415.mp4`, where `1709532255` is always an epoch time.

I found that

```
date -d @1708532255 +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'
```

... gives me the wanted format, but I can't get it to work in the script.

Here my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /media/HAVideo/Eingang/Test/2/*.mp4
do
filename=`echo "${file}" | cut -d'.' -f1`
readable=`date -d @$filename +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
mv "${file}" "${readable}"
done
```

The output is:

```
...
date: invalid date '@/media/HAVideo/Eingang/Test/2/1709532255'
mv: can't rename '/media/HAVideo/Eingang/Test/2/1709532255.mp4': No such file or directory
...
```

Comment: I am guessing you need to apply it to a var of some sort, so try `new_date=$(date -d @1708532255 +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')`

Comment: try remove the @ in front of $filename.. does that help?

Comment: removing the @ shows error: date: invalid date '/media/HAVideo/Eingang/Test/2/1709532255'

Comment: it looks like its treating the whole file path as the filename, hence the 'invalid date'
maybe use the basename command to get just the filename

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just missed a `cd`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /media/HAVideo/Eingang/Test/2/ || exit # <- what changed
for file in *.mp4
do
filename=`echo "${file}" | cut -d'.' -f1`
readable=`date -d @$filename +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S.mp4"`
mv "${file}" "${readable}"
done
```

But there's some issues.

Use `$( )` instead of backticks. And indent properly.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

A better version:

```
#!/bin/bash -

cd /media/HAVideo/Eingang/Test/2/ || exit
for file in *.mp4 ; do
    mv -- "$file" "$(date -d "@${file%.*}" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S.mp4")"
done
```

---

`${file%.*}` is a builtin *parameter expansion*

See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 and
`LESS='+/Parameter Expansion' man bash`
Also see [wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe](https://web.archive.org/web/20230108022244/http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Since that's a standard `sh` operator (from ksh) and there's no bashism in that code, you could change the shebang to `#! /bin/sh -` and remove the bash dependency. That `date -d` is a non-standard GNUism though, which you could avoid by using the `printf '%(format)T'` of recent versions of bash (copied from ksh93).

Comment: is working perfect for me, thanks

Comment: Note that the [`-` in the `#! /bin/bash -` shebang was added intentionally](/q/351729).

Comment: Use `+"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.mp4"` to get the requested timestamp format and filename suffix.

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
$ zmodload zsh/datetime
$ autoload zmv
$ cd /media/HAVideo/Eingang/Test/2/
$ zmv -n '(<->)(.mp4)' '$(strftime %Y%m%d_%H%M%S $1)$2'
mv -- 1709532255.mp4 20240304_060415.mp4
```

(remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy).

Beware that while 1709532255 is timezone independent, `20240304_060415` is not and is ambiguous. You can remove the ambiguity and still use local time by using ISO8601-style date format where the offset to UTC is included by replacing `%Y%m%d_%H%M%S` with `%FT%T%z` for instance, where I'd get `2024-03-04T06:04:15+0000` and you'd likely get `2024-03-04T07:04:15+0100`, same timestamp, but in two different timezones.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are seeing the error:

```
date: invalid date '@/media/HAVideo/Eingang/Test/2/1709532255'
```

is because you are passing the full path of the file, minus the extension, due to your `cut` command.

```
[...snipped out irrelevant parts...]
filename=`echo "${file}" | cut -d'.' -f1`
...
readable=`date -d @$filename +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
```

is evaluating to:

```
readable=`date -d @/media/HAVideo/Eingang/Test/2/1709532255 +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
```

Therefore, `filename` is `/media/HAVideo/Eingang/Test/2/1709532255`.

Your script mostly works. I modified the `filename=...` line to retrieve only the basename of the file, instead of the full path:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /media/HAVideo/Eingang/Test/2/*.mp4
do
filename=`basename "${file}" | cut -d'.' -f1`
readable=`date -d @$filename +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
mv "${file}" "${readable}"
done
```

of course, you could go further and remove the unnecessary `cut` since `basename` can remove the file extension, and rename the variables so the code is a little clearer:

```
for src in /media/HAVideo/Eingang/Test/2/*.mp4
do
  epoch="$(basename "$src" .mp4)"
  dst="$(date -d "@$epoch" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")"
  mv "$src" "$dst"
done
```

Comment: The only downside I see here is that this appears to move files from `/media/HAVideo/Eingang/Test/2/` to the present directory. This can be corrected by putting the directory in front of `"$dst"`, or by using `cd` to change directory. +1 for using `basename`, particularly the second parameter (removing the extension).

Comment: I didn't include that behavior because it wasn't clear from the question that the author intended for the script to behave that way. However, I completely agree with you. In practice keeping all files in the same directory would be the least surprising

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I now have a version that works well for me. But of course I learn from you with every comment.

Answer (score 1):

NOT TESTED

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function to convert epoch time to date_time format
epoch_to_datetime () {
  date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S --date="@$1"
}

# Loop through all files in the current directory
for file in *.mp4; do
  # Extract epoch time from filename (assuming it's the first part)
  epoch_time="${file%%.*}"

  # Convert epoch time to date_time format
  new_filename="$(epoch_to_datetime $epoch_time)"_$(basename "$file")

  # Rename the file using mv command
  mv "$file" "$new_filename"
  echo "Renamed: $file -> $new_filename"
done
```

Comment: Wouldn't this include the old filename in the new name?

Comment: Well spotted. Yes it looks that way. Like I said, I did not test it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) (usable in any OS).

```
perl -MTime::Piece -e '
    for (@ARGV) {
        my $file = $_;
        s/\..*$//;
        rename $file, Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%s")->strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    }
' *.mp4
```

---

[`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece)'s module is packed with Perl, no need to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Some guys offered their solutions, so I focused on 2 things.

1. To do as less modifications as possible
2. To get rid of unnecessary failsafe syntax

   ```
    for file in /media/HAVideo/Eingang/Test/2/*.mp4 ; do # it is better to do it in one line
      filename=`echo ${file##*/} | cut -d'.' -f1` # we are using globbing here
      readable=`date -d @$filename +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"` 
      mv $file $readable
    done
   ```

In real world production there are plenty occasions where you can not get spaces within filenames under any conditions. So I personally advice to get rid of unnecessary quotation in past 2 lines of the cycle.

You can do it if you know exactly what you are doing. Then you will have better, cleaner syntax in your scripts.

Also a word about backticks. I like the advice from the highest ranked answer above. It is usually better to use $() form. Still there's no big issue with backticks unless you're starting to make inclusions like  `\` ` `.